# Запятая перед КАК

Tags: как, пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед *как*:

> В свое время история их написания
> захватила меня как детектив.

Answer (score 4):

Запятая нужна, чистый сравнительный оборот. "Захватила, как будто детектив".

Comment: Согласна полностью,нет значения "в качестве", нельзя заменить творительным падежом. (Это я для автора вопроса, чтоб она отбросила сомнения)

Answer (score 3):

В комментарий не умещается, отвечаю Вере здесь.

Проверка "в качестве" здесь вообще не подходит (это же не тождество, а сравнительный оборот).

Вот именно, если тождество или приравнивание, то запятой нет, а здесь как раз сравнительный оборот, УПОДОБЛЕНИЕ. Согласна с Верой только в том, что, к сожалению, не всегда обстоятельства образа действия можно с полной уверенностью отличить от обстоятельств сравнения, но чаще всего обстоятельство образа действия можно заменить наречием или сущ. в творит. пад. В нашем случае это невозможно, значит, можно использовать как ОДИН ИЗ случаев проверки (вместе с другими). А другие тоже в правилах есть:

[Не обособляются обороты с союзом КАК в пяти случаях:](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183)

1. Если оборот с союзом КАК в предложении выступает в роли обстоятельства образа действия.
2. Если оборот с союзом КАК входит в состав фразеологизма, например: *Во время обеда она сидела как на иголках.*
3. Если оборот с союзом КАК входит в состав сказуемого и предложение без такого оборота не имеет законченного смысла, например: *Она держится как хозяйка.*
4. Если союз КАК стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым (без этого союза там требовалось бы поставить тире), например: *Озеро как зеркало.*
5. Если сравнительному обороту предшествует отрицание НЕ или частицы СОВСЕМ, СОВЕРШЕННО, ПОЧТИ, ВРОДЕ, ТОЧЬ-В-ТОЧЬ, ИМЕННО, ПРОСТО, например: *Они все делают не как соседи* или *Волосы у нее вьются точь-в-точь как у матери.*

В нашем случае вполне подойдёт случай:  Запятыми выделяются или отделяются обороты, начинающиеся союзом "КАК":

1) если они обозначают уподобление, без других оттенков значения ("КАК" имеет значение «подобно»).
Например: *Вокруг высокого чела, как тучи, локоны чернеют.* (Пушкин)  *Внизу, как зеркало стальное, синеют озера струи.* (Тютчев)    *Её голос звенел, как колокольчик.  Руки его дрожали, как ртуть.* (Гоголь)

http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/317-zapyatayaperedsyuzomkak.html

Можно сомневаться в примере "Её голос звенел, как колокольчик", но здесь явно голос сравнивается с колокольчиком, если сказать "звенел колокольчиком", т. е. звонко, получится тавтология" звенел звонко", а другого синонима-обстоятельства  не подобрать.

В нашем случае напрашивается "так": "захватила, так, как захватывает детектив" - сравниваются действия.

Вариант "В свое время история их написания захватила меня как детектив" звучит странно. Какой из случаев "непостановки" запятой здесь применить? Ничего не подходит.

Comment: Вот примеры. А) Тропинка извивается как змея (по-змеиному). Как град (градом) посыпалась картечь. Б)Тропинка, как змея, извивается между деревьями.Картечь, как град, посыпалась со всех сторон. Это правильно? Если да, то прокомментируйте, пожалуйста, разные решения с использованием приведенных выше правил.

Comment: Розенталь: При анализе подобных примеров мы исходим из авторской пунктуации и пытаемся ее объяснить, что, как известно, является делом весьма сложным. Так, мы можем допустить, что в предложении "Она ускользнёт, как змея, порхнёт и умчится, как птичка" автору важно было создать художественные образы путем, так сказать, чистого сравнения (подобно змее, подобно птичке, хотя сравнение сохраняется и в сочетаниях ускользнёт змеёй, умчится птичкой, но с добавочным оттенком образа действия).

Comment: Но двойственность акцентов (на образе объекта или образе действия)возможна там, где допускается образ действия. В анализируемом примере его нет. Запятая нужна.

Comment: Русская речь выражает определенный смысл. При желании автор может реализовать свои любые замыслы и воплотить разнообразные художественные образы, это его право. Однако при этом он должен УМЕЛО ПОЛЬЗОВАТЬСЯ ФОРМОЙ ДЛЯ ВЫРАЖЕНИЯ НУЖНОГО ЕМУ СОДЕРЖАНИЯ. Это означает, что структура предложения должна ПОЗВОЛИТЬ нужный оборот обособить. Если есть такое желание, то осуществить его несложно:  измените порядок слов, увеличьте объем сообщения.

Comment: Но вот что интересно: заданное предложение с необособленным оборотом выглядит вполне достойно,читается легко, по смыслу понятно. Так зачем портить его  ненужными паузами и запятыми только в угоду "правильным" правилам. Да и правила-то не нарушаются: согласно правилам, сравнительный оборот МОЖЕТ входить в основное сообщение и не обособляться.

Comment: Да, но если сказуемое без оборота вообще не имеет смысла (Он выглядел... как ребенок) или требует конкретизации, при которой смысл меняется (Я смотрела на нее... как на сестру). Убирая запятую, мы подчеркиваем СВЯЗЬ СО СКАЗУЕМЫМ, влияющую на СМЫСЛ. В нашем примере запятая передает определенный смысл. Ср.: Эта история захватила меня, как детектив (так, как захватывает детектив). Эта история захватила меня как детектив (а как мелодрама не захватила = я воспринял ее в качестве детектива).

Comment: Тat, вы хотите управлять смыслом на письме с помощью запятых, и все хотят поступать точно так же. Но только этот же смысл в  УСТНОЙ РЕЧИ запятыми уже не выразишь. Попробуем расставить ударения: "В свое время история их написАния (ПЗ) захватила меня как детектИв". Всё красиво и гармонично. А с запятой что получится? Вот у меня ничего не получается, надо выделять или "захватИла", или "менЯ", дальше пауза. Ну не читается предложение такого объема с коротким сравнительным оборотом на конце, как бы этого ни хотелось.

Comment: А при чем здесь устная речь? Знаки препинания бывают структурные, смысловые и интонационные. Структурные и смысловые не всегда передаются паузами. Кроме того, есть паузы, которые не обозначаются знаками препинания. "В свое время история их написания захватила меня как детектив" - произносим без паузы в конце, а запятую ставим, чтобы обозначить, что история не была детективной по своей сути, а была просто увлекательной.

Comment: Вера, а у Гоголя короткий сравнительный оборот на конце читается? "Руки его дрожали, как ртуть". (Гоголь)Здесь тоже явное сравнение, а не обстоятельство образа действия. Вот и "как детектив" не обстоятельство образа действия, или, как Вы говорите,не "входит в основное сообщение". Только я так и не поняла, о каком сообщении идёт речь - о грамматической основе? А то сравнение тоже обстоятельство, только сравнительное.

Comment:  А) Тропинка извивается как змея (по-змеиному).-обстоятельство образа действия=волнисто. Как град (градом) посыпалась картечь-обст. обр.действия = плотно, потоком. Б) Тропинка, как змея, извивается между деревьями.--Тропинка сравнивается со змеёй на основе сходства по волнистости Картечь, как град, посыпалась со всех сторон.- картечь сравнивается с градом на основе сходства по внешнему виду(круглые шарики) Всё по правилам, легко объясняется и читается.

Comment: Только нет смысла сравнивать картечь с градом, потому чаще в этом случае всё же без запятых. Вера, я понимаю Вашу мысль об интуиции, но этому не научишь-она или есть, или её нет,а вот правила знать надо(если надо, а то и так некоторые живут, и ещё получше грамотных). Обидно, что обесцениваются знания в наше время, но я рада, что на таких сайтах, как наш, много молодых людей - значит, не всё потеряно.Пусть учат правила, а мы поможем в них разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Мне задача не кажется однозначной.

Я беру несколько примеров, и такое впечатление, что они должны писаться по-разному: сравнительный оборот может входить в основное сообщение и не обособляться, являясь обстоятельством образа действия. Но может обособляться при наличии местоимения "так" или другого обстоятельства. Проверки же, они всегда формальны, а проверка "в качестве" здесь вообще не подходит (это же не тождество, а сравнительный оборот), надо учитывать СТРУКТУРУ предложения.

ПРИМЕРЫ

В свое время история их написания захватила меня так, как детектив.
Я давняя поклонница Ваших песен и прочитала Вашу книгу, как детектив, почти не отрываясь.
Доклад «РЭНД» читаешь как детектив.

ПРИВЕДЕННЫЙ ПРИМЕР (КАК ВОЗМОЖНЫЙ ВАРИАНТ РЕШЕНИЯ)

В свое время история их написания захватила меня как детектив.

Но: В свое время история их написания, как детектив, целиком захватила меня (распространение предложения позволяет обособить оборот).

Интересно, что выражение "история захватила" редко встречается без распространителей, обычно захватила "вдруг, целиком, полностью, тогда, в то время" и т.д. В нашем случае таким распространителем может быть необособленный сравнительный оборот, входящий в основную часть предложения.

Comment: Тat, отвечаю Вам здесь, чтобы завершить наш интересный диалог. Знаете, любая наука - это один из способов описания действительности. Представьте, что перед нами грамотно написанный текст на русском языке. Два человека, не знающие никаких правил, начинают анализировать его, при этом каждый делает свои выводы, составляет свое собственное описание и свои правила письма. Люди, которые будут прилежно учиться по этим правилам, в обоих случаях будут писать грамотно (один результат), а правила разные, подход разный.

Comment: Так вот, у нас с вами разный подход, вряд ли мы поймем друг друга. Вы считаете, что "знаки препинания бывают структурные, смысловые и интонационные и т.д. Я считаю, что русская пунктуация построена на ЕДИНСТВЕ семантического, грамматического и интонационного принципов. Да, у нас разные точки зрения на систему письма, но достаточно близкие по совпадению результаты, за исключением отдельных спорных моментов. Наверное, это не так плохо: пользователь может выбрать то, что его больше устраивает.

Comment: Вера, я понимаю, что вы хотите сказать. Передать эту запятую интонационно сложно (попробуйте так: В свое время история их написания захватила меня. Как детектив). Я просто хочу понять, за что вы ратуете: за свободу от ненужных правил? И тут же навязываете новые? Вы оставляете такой выбор: (1) писать без запятой и ломать голову, была история детективной или нет; (2) говорящему следить за своей речью и перестраивать предложения, чтобы запятые легко передавались интонационно. А если человек сказал в интервью "эта история захватила меня, как детектив"? Чем ясность с запятой хуже неясности без?

Comment: У меня просто есть мечта: научить людей, знающих грамматический минимум, писать по слуху, а не по правилам. И чтобы получалось так, как будто они все правила знают, и не только знают, а умеют смысл каждого правила объяснить. А писать постоянно по правилам - это все равно что ходить постоянно по правилам. Большинство практически грамотных людей в правила не углубляются, а пишут по интуиции, а это и значит по слуху.

Comment: Кстати, запятая в этом предложении им слух портит. И еще: сочетание " захватила ка детектив" имеет один-единственный смысл - "захватила целиком" и практически его можно приравнять к устойчивому выражению.

Comment: Вера, интуиция может и подвести. Грамотными людьми не становятся просто так. Чтобы научиться грамотно писать и ставить запятые, надо хоть знать школьный минимум. 

Вот, например, взять вас:  я не поверю, если вы скажите, если ставите знаки препинания по интуиции. Раз вы консультируете здесь, то и правила знаете, а значит, опираетесь на них.

Comment: Это очень интересная тема, только, по-моему, задача без решения. Вот чем, например, объяснить то, что тьма-тьмущая "стихийно грамотных" людей ставит запятую после "то есть". Их интонация ее требует. Настроить правильную интонацию - все равно что развить музыкальный слух. Далеко не всем по силам. А факультативные обособления... У некоторых просто страсть к акцентированию всех слов в предложении. Как отучить от интонационной чрезмерности? Потому и в актеры берут не всех, что не чувствуют люди интонации. Хорошо бы для начала составить перечень основных ошибок, связанных с неправильным "слухом".

Answer (score 0):

Вера, русская пунктуация сформировалась за долго до нас с вами. И как отметил Тат, она основано на трех принципах: Структурным( главный признак), смысловой, и интонационный.

Надо отметить,что буквального совпадения между знаками препинания и интонацией нет.

> 1) ***В предложении Краткие речи/всегда более со­держательны/и способны вызвать сильное впечатление (М. Горький) три паузы, а знаков препинания нет.***
>
> 2)В предложении *Под мышкой мальчик нёс какой-то узел и, повернув к пристани, стал спускаться по узкой и крутой тропинке (*М. Лермонтов) **между союзом и и дееприча­стием повернув запятая есть, а пауза в устной речи отсут­ствует; наоборот, перед этим союзом есть пауза, а запятой нет.**

Поэтому я не понимаю заявления: я считаю так. Мы с вами много что можем считать. Но это не значит, что правильно так, как мы с вами считаем.
P.S. Кстати, я тоже присоединяюсь к остальным участникам, ответившим, что запятая перед ''как'' нужна. 
В предложении смысл очевиден. Здесь сравнение. ***Захватила так, как будто была детективом.*** Предложение без оборота ''как'' является законченным, оборот не входит в состав сказуемого.  Тат все логично объяснила.

Comment: Тат, я правильно написал окончание: объяснил**А**?

Comment: Да, я девочка:)

Comment: Ну что ж, мне трудно отвечать всем, мы не слышим друг друга, у меня нет единомышленников. Я сдаюсь, классики победили новую идеологию с разгромным счетом. Vera больше не участвует в дискуссиях. Может быть, иногда будет просто давать ответы на текущие вопросы.

Comment: Вера, дело не чей-то победе, как Вам кажется. Просто есть правила, на которые мы с вами должны ориентироваться. Даже если это противоречит нашим мнениям. Вот и все. Таков наш язык.

Comment: Красиво сказано, Серж. Приятно чувствовать себя правым и правильным. Вот вы говорите, что пунктуация в вашем понимании основана на трех принципах. Об этом говорится во вступительной части учебников, но сами правила основаны на произвольной смеси грамматики и семантики при практически полном непонимании интонации. Чтобы понимать интонацию,надо знать ее природу, ее составные части.А у классиков вся интонация в лучшем случае заключается в наличии или отсутствии пауз, или о ней забывается вообще.

Comment: Вера, но в то время правила еще были достаточно разработаны. Отчасти вы правы, говоря о классиках.
Вот что пишет Достоевский: ''У каждого автора свой собственный слог,и потому своя собственная грамматика...Мне нет никакого дела до чужих правил!  Я ставлю запятую перед ''что'' где она мне нужна; а где я чувствую, что  не надо перед ''что'' ставить запятую,там я ее не хочу, чтоб мне ее ставили!'' ''Вы имейте в виду, - говорил Достоевский, - что у меня ни одной лишней запятой нет, все необходимые только; прошу не прибавлять и не убавлять их у меня''.

Comment: Да,интересная запись. Получается,что один единомышленник у меня всё-таки  нашелся,хотя и в прошлом. По интонации, по структуре, должно быть, чувствовал текст, настоящий художник слова. Спасибо, Серж, мне уже не так одиноко.

Comment: Как видно, у Достоевского было много самовольный знаков препинания, которые не нужны были по правилам, но он их ставил, потому что, по его мнению, он придавал особый смысл и путем синтаксической паузы подчеркивал то или иное слово слово.